# retriving data in the validation and serialization. problem with fastify

Tags: node.js, validation, serialization, joi, fastify

Fastify validation-and-serialization problem:

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')

fastify.post('/the/url', {
  schema: {
    body: Joi.object().keys({
      hello: Joi.string().required()
    }).required()
  },
  validatorCompiler: ({ schema, method, url, httpPart }) => {
    return data => schema.validate(data)
  }
}, handler)
```

My problem is how can I use the data validated in the handler function.
So after validating the data of req.body:

```
, handler: (req,reply) => { // how can i retrieve the filtered data ? }
```

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a route option for this: [`attachValidation`](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Routes/#options)

```
const fastify = require('./')()
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')

fastify.post('/the/url', {
  schema: {
    body: Joi.object().keys({
      hello: Joi.string().required()
    }).required()
  },
  attachValidation: true,
  validatorCompiler: ({ schema, method, url, httpPart }) => {
    return data => schema.validate(data)
  }
}, (request) => {
  console.log(request.validationError)
})

fastify.inject({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/the/url',
  payload: {}
})
```